# Solve the separable differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This question is really basic but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.. Any help is appreciated.

> $$y' = 6y^2$$

Using the initial condition: $y(6) = 3$, find $y(1)$.

I tried this by integrating and finding $c$, but this concept isn't making sense to me, and looking at other more complex questions isn't clearing things up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the equation is separable, we write
$$\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &= 6y^2\\
\dfrac{dy}{y^2} &= 6\,dx
\end{aligned}$$
Then, integrating both sides, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\int \dfrac{dy}{y^2} &= \int 6\,dx\\
-\dfrac{1}{y} &= 6x + \mbox{C}
\end{aligned}$$
Since $y(6) = 3$,
$$\begin{aligned}
-\dfrac{1}{3} &= 36 + \mbox{C}\\
\mbox{C} &= -\dfrac{109}{3}
\end{aligned}$$
Thus, we obtain
$$-\dfrac{1}{y} = 6x - \dfrac{109}{3}$$
Find $y(1)$, and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

First, write it like this
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=6y^2$$
then separate dy and dx
$$(y^{-2})dy=(6)dx$$
then integrate
$$\int(y^{-2})dy\int(6)dx$$

I hope this isn't too much or too little help, it should be a good start.

Comment: Thank you as well, I'm figuring it out now thanks to the quick replies.